# Net mvc 3 complex model send form data to controller save to database

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, editorformodel

I am trying to pass a dynamic complex model to my controller, without using and Editor View Template.  After adding items, my mark up ends up looking like the following.

```
<ul>
    <li class="invItem">
        <input type="hidden" value="Bed California King" name="[0].efInvItem">
        <input type="hidden" value="4" name="[0].efRoomID"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close removeItem"></span>Bed California King
    </li>
    <li class="invItem"><input type="hidden" value="Coffee Table Medium" name="[1].efInvItem">
    <input type="hidden" value="4" name="[1].efRoomID"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-close removeItem"></span>Coffee Table Medium
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="addItem">Add inventory item to this room</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am using javascript, not an Editor View Template to create the list.  When adding an item to this list I am renaming all the input elements so that I have an ordered list of input items.

I am then receiving the form items in the controller via

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SendEstimate(ICollection<EstimateFormInventory> intentoryItems)
```

Following the suggested procedure after reading this post

```
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx
```

and then saving the items to the database via

```
db.EstimateFormInventory.Add(estimateFormInventory);
db.SaveChanges();
```

However, the ICollection is not being iterated through when posting to the db, and I am getting 1 row created with null values.

My model looks like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace OCMovers.Models
{
    public class EstimateFormInventory
    {
        [Key]
        public int efiID { get; set; }
        public virtual Room efRoomID { get; set; } 
        public string efiInvItem { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm definitely missing something, any suggestions would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: "the ICollection is not being iterated through" so you did a `foreach` on it and it's empty or what?

Comment: I think this is where Im confused -- No i did not do a foreach in the controller, I was under the impression that by passing the ICollection to the controller, and that all the input fields are ordered sequentially, that it would be taken care of when doing the .Add.